# invalid sessiontoken when converting anonymous user to signed in user in parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm using Swift on iOS.

My app has  a list of posts. You can read anonymously but you have to sign up to post.

When you open the app you get an anonymous account. I put the following in  AppDelegate

```
PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
PFUser.currentUser()?.incrementKey("RunCount")
PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
```

I got the code from: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-anonymous-users

When you go to post I have you sign up

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
user?.username = displayNameTextField.text
user?.password = passwordTextField.text
user?.email = emailTextField.text
user!.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock { ... }
```

This succeeds. I can see the user being updated on the server. However I get a 209 error: [Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.4)

I have tried looking at the sessiontoken and printing it out at every step and it remains the same. I have heard that sessiontokens are invalidated when a user logs out but I thought I just signed a user in and not out. Why is the sessiontoken invalid?

I have tried setting the user as the current user with PFUser.Become() using the sessiontoken but that does not work either.

I am clearly overlooking something but I can't figure out what. Any help is much appreciate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same problem started happening for me, and I realised it was due to enabling this option in the app settings:

```
Revoke existing session tokens when user changes password - YES/NO
```

I suspect this is an unintended side-effect of setting a password on an anonymous user - I don't think there's any reason the session token would need to be reset in this case.

Hopefully this will be fixed, but a work-around is to call the logInWithUsername method right after the signUp method succeeds.

Comment: Thank you. Clever. 

May I ask, did you start pick "New Project" or "Existing Project?"

"New Project" gives you a blank Xcode project. "Existing Project" gives you a guide for how to add the Parse Framework to your existing Xcode project. 

I started with an Existing Project, but I just tried to reproduce the problem to test your solution and started with "New Project" and I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Personally I always start with my own blank Xcode project and add Parse using the 'Existing Project' method. This won't have any impact on the problem though - the setting I'm talking about is in the "Settings/General" section for your app on www.parse.com. I've reproduced the issue in the blank starter project and submitted it as a bug to Parse.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the login correctly, try this

```
func login() {
  var user = PFUser()
  user.username = "myUsername"
  user.password = "myPassword"
  user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
      let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? NSString
      // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    } else {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    }
  }
}
```

The code `let user = PFUser.currentUser()` only show the user currently logged in.

You also have to authenticate with Parse before you can create any request, the best place to do it is in `appDelegate` inside the function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        Parse.setApplicationId("Your Id go Here", clientKey: "Your clientKey go here")
    return true
}
```

The values for ID and clientKey is available in Parse and is unique for your accont

I hope that helps you, good luck!

Comment: Thanks you but that gives me the same result. Invalid session tokens.

Comment: Thank you but I am already authenticated with parse. I'm beginning to wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: I doubt is a bug as I use it many times, double check your keys and ID maybe you are using it from a different project

Comment: May I ask, did you start pick "New Project" or "Existing Project?"

"New Project" gives you a blank Xcode project. "Existing Project" gives you a guide for how to add the Parse Framework to your existing Xcode project.